# Selenium : How to start the web browser with no cache

Tags: java, selenium, caching, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone help me what are the possible way to test this scenario

Scenario:
Once you fill up the form (page A) , it will redirect to a specific page (Page B).
When you try to access again the link of (Page A) you will automatically redirect to **Page B** so now I just wondering if there is a way to handle the cache without deleting the cache directly to browser settings. so once I run again my test suite , I will be able to view again the Form in Page A

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Selenium uses by default a temporary browser profile which is created in every single driver instance creating. If you do not specify to load selenium with specific existing browser profile browser will always start with empty cache.